# How to update parent and all children of One-to-Many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, one-to-many, entity-framework-6

Suppose I have the following two entities with a one-to-many relationship where one Report can have many LineItems. These entities have been created using Entity Foundation 6 Code First.

```
public class Report
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public DateTime ReportDate{ get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<LineItems> LineItems { get; set;}
}

public class LineItems
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string ItemDescription{ get; set;}
    public virtual Report Report { get; set;}
}
```

I have the following in my Controller and View.

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    private CodeFirstContext context = new CodeFirstContext();
    ...
    Report rep = context.Reports.Include(x => x.LineItems).Single(x => x.ID == id);
    if(TryUpdateModel(rep, "", new string[] {"ReportDate"}))
    {
        foreach(var item in rep.LineItems)
        {
            if(TryUpdateModel(item, "item", new string[] {"ItemDescription"}))
            {
                context.LineItems.Attach(item);
                context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        context.Entry(rep).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        ...
    }
}
```

View:

```
...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportDate);

@foreach (var item in Model.LineItems)
{
    @html.EditorFor(i => item.ItemDescription);
}
...
```

I need to be able to update a single Report and all of its related LineItems in the same view. There could be any number of LineItems associated with a single Report. When I submit the updates with my current setup, all data is successfully saved; but the data for most of the child LineItems is incorrect. The first child is correct and then all subsequent LineItems are saved with the data from the first LineItem rather than the data from their respective inputs.

I've looked at the html source that is generated by the page and all of the LineItem inputs have the same id, name, etc. in the form "item_ItemDescription" or "item.ItemDescription". I'm pretty sure that what is happening is that because they all have the same identifiers, the data is just being pulled from the first input on the page that has those identifiers.

So how can I specify which input goes with which LineItem? It seems strange to me that the foreach statement does not just automatically create unique identifiers for each input within it.

**SOLVED**

As py3r3str suggested, I had to change my view to use a for loop rather than a foreach and add a HiddenFor to hold the ID for each entity. I had to change my models to use:

```
public virtual IList<LineItems> LineItems {get; set;}
```

because ICollection does not have an index associated with it.

I had to change the controller to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Report report) //changed argument from id to Report
{
    private CodeFirstContext context = new CodeFirstContext();
    ...
    //following line unnecessary with new report argument
    //Report rep = context.Reports.Include(x => x.LineItems).Single(x => x.ID == id);
    if(TryUpdateModel(report, "", new string[] {"ReportDate"}))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < report.LineItems.Count; i++) //change to for loop
        {
            if(TryUpdateModel(report.LineItems[i], "", new string[] {"ItemDescription"}))
            {
                //removed following line. Update does not work with it in there.
                //context.LineItems.Attach(report.LineItems[i]);
                context.Entry(report.LineItems[i]).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        context.Entry(report).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make MVC map your post data correctly, you have to change your view code to:

```
...
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID);
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportDate);

@for (var i; i < Model.LineItems.Count; i++)
{
    @html.HiddenFor(e => Model.LineItems[i].ID);
    @html.EditorFor(e => Model.LineItems[i].ItemDescription);
}
...
```

Then your model can be maped by MVC controller:

```
...
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Report raport)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do save stuff
    }
}
...
```